# Windows: Settign the position of child window correctly in a two monitor setup

Tags: windows, qt, unity-game-engine, qml

I'm doing some testing with a VERY simple unity application inside a Qt/QML application. I've gotten it to work (open up the application and run the unity application inside the Qt app) just fine, however I'm having trouble witht he window position.

I'm working of a laptop that has a 1920x1080 resolution monitor.
Connected to it I have 4K monitor (resolution 3840x2160).

Here is the Debug Code I'm running. Every time the QML parent window is resized or moved I do:

```
    console.log("QML WINDOW: (" + x + "," + y +") " + width + "x" + height);
    control.printWindowParameters(frame.x,frame.y);
```

Where frame is just a QML Rectangle that I use as a target. The print windows parameter function looks like this:

```
void printWindowParameters(int target_x, int target_y){

    RECT window_rectangle, client_rectangle;
    GetWindowRect((HWND) mainWindowID, &window_rectangle);
    GetClientRect((HWND) mainWindowID, &client_rectangle);
    
    qint32 wh = window_rectangle.bottom - window_rectangle.top;
    qint32 ww = window_rectangle.right - window_rectangle.left;
    qint32 ch = client_rectangle.bottom - client_rectangle.top;
    qint32 cw = client_rectangle.right - client_rectangle.left;
    qint32 dW = ww - cw;
    qint32 dH = wh - ch;
    
    if ((dW < 0) || (dH < 0)) return;
    
    
    qDebug() << "Window Rectangle: (" << window_rectangle.left << "," << window_rectangle.top << ")" << ww << "x" << wh;
    qDebug() << "Client Rectangle: (" << client_rectangle.left << "," << client_rectangle.top << ")" << cw << "x" << ch;
    qDebug() << "Win - Client. H:" << dH << ". W" << dW << ". Target Coordinates (" << target_x << "," << target_y << ")";
    
    qint32 x = target_x;
    qint32 y = target_y;
    qint32 h = 300;
    qint32 w = 300;
    
    qDebug() << "Setting inner window to (" << x << "," << y << ")" << w << "x" << h;
    
    MoveWindow(child_window_handle,x,y,w,h,TRUE);
}
```

My idea is that top, left corner of the child window (the one running the unity app) should always coincides with top left corner of the rectagle "frame".

This works just fine in the laptop monitor. Here is how it looks when maximized
[image]

And this is what is printed out:

```
qml: QML WINDOW: (0,23) 1920x1017
Window Rectangle: ( -8 , -8 ) 1936 x 1056
Client Rectangle: ( 0 , 0 ) 1920 x 1017
Win - Client. H: 39 . W 16 . Target Coordinates ( 288 , 101 )
Setting inner window to ( 288 , 101 ) 300 x 300
```

However whenever I move the application to the secondary monitor (the big 4K one) the corners no longer coincide. This is what it looks like maximized
[image]

And this is what is printed out:

```
qml: QML WINDOW: (-3840,23) 2560x1377
Window Rectangle: ( -3851 , -11 ) 3862 x 2122
Client Rectangle: ( 0 , 0 ) 3840 x 2066
Win - Client. H: 56 . W 22 . Target Coordinates ( 384 , 137 )
Setting inner window to ( 384 , 137 ) 300 x 300
```

According to the documentation for MoveWindow, the positioning should be relative to the client window area, which always has a top left corner of zero zero. So my undertanding is that the code should work in both monitors with no issue.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: What is target_x and target_y was they dont seem recalculated

Comment: They are the coordinates for the top left corner of the "frame" in qml.

Comment: @BugFinder I realized I did not add the function definition so I addeed it to make it clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So In case it helps anyone, the culprit was the Scale factor used for the secondary display, and NOT the secondary display itself. Basically the values provided by the application for positioning within the application are based on a 100% Scale. When you scale to something larger (very common in hi resolution display with small screens like Full HD laptop monitors or 4K monitors) then math needs to be done in order to properly place the window. The code looks like this:

```
    quint32 DPI = GetDpiForWindow((HWND) mainWindowID);

    float dpi_multiplier = static_cast<float>(DPI)/96.0f;

    qint32 x = static_cast<qint32>( static_cast<float>(target_x)*dpi_multiplier );
    qint32 y = static_cast<qint32>( static_cast<float>(target_y)*dpi_multiplier );
    qint32 w = static_cast<qint32>( static_cast<float>(target_w)*dpi_multiplier );
    qitn32 h = static_cast<qint32>( static_cast<float>(target_h)*dpi_multiplier );

    MoveWindow(child_window_handle,x,y,w,h,TRUE);
```

This will propertly scale the IN WINDOW coordinates and sizes according the the Scaling selected by the Windows User.

Comment: You may need to check out https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html specifically `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);`

Comment: Thanks, But I (withouth knowing really) handled the resolution change manually including sizes and fonts. The applciation itself looks fine. It was just this scaling that screw over the inner window.